# Check if string contains number

Tags: excel

I have a big address file with *street + housenumber* in one column.
I want to check how many addresses there are without *housenumber*.

So actually I'm just trying to check if the cells contain a number anywhere

I tried a number of things,

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A500;{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
=COUNTIF(A1:A500;"*>0*")
```

but none seemed to work

```
Streetname 5 should return TRUE
5 Streetname should return TRUE
Streetname five should return FALSE
Streetname should return FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))>0
```

You need to check each cell individually. Using the curly brackets generates an array so if any digit is found, FIND returns a number and COUNT goes up by 1.

If no digits are found, COUNT returns 0 and the formula shows FALSE.

[image]

Comment: What if there are streetnames like `5th Avenue`?

Comment: @JvdV I don't think that is part of the OP? :) This is the best way to go I think.

Comment: Yeah for sure it's a good way, but I am just thinking about the tricky part of the solution, which is how to differentiate between the position of the found number being part of the streetname or a sole housenumber.

Comment: @JvdV - don't know what the correct answer is, but if differentation is required then I would go regexp.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind the cleanest way to do this is to use regular expressions.  Add a VBA module to the workbook with the following function:

```
Public Function rxTest(inputString As String, pattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim r As New RegExp

    r.pattern = pattern
    rxTest = r.Test(inputString)
End Function
```

(you will need to add a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions`).  Then the following formula will do what you want for each cell and you can count the number of `TRUE` cells:

```
= rxTest(A1,"\d")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with your `COUNTIF` function.  But since your function contains an array constant, it will return an array of values.

To *check how many addresses there are without housenumber*:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A100)-SUM(N(COUNTIF(A1:A100,"*" &{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}&"*")>0))
```

To return `TRUE/FALSE` depending on the contents of an individual cell, you can use this formula:

```
=OR(COUNTIF(A1,"*" &{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}&"*")>0)
```

**Note** as pointed out in a comment to another question, this will only detect if there is a digit in the string.  It will not differentiate strings where the street name includes a number (eg *5th Ave*) from strings that include address numbers.  It also won't detect an address where the address number is spelled out (eg *One Drury Avenue*)